# 4D integral with bounds

Tags: probability, integration

What is the answer for the following integral?

$\int\int\int e^{-\lambda(x+y+z)}dx\ dy\ dz$

bounded to:

$x+y < \tau,\ y+z<\tau\ ,x \ge 0,\ y \ge 0,\ z \ge 0$

Comment: What have you attempted.  **Hint:** reordering gives: $0\leq x\,,\,x+y< \tau\,,\,y+z<\tau\,,\,0\leq z$

Answer (score 1):

Just put the right bounds and have some patience:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\int_{0}^{\tau}\int_{0}^{\tau-x}\int_{0}^{\tau-y}e^{-\lambda x}e^{-\lambda y}e^{-\lambda z}\,dz\,dy\,dx &=&\frac{1}{\lambda}\int_{0}^{\tau}\int_{0}^{\tau-x}e^{-\lambda x}e^{-\lambda y}\left(1-e^{-\lambda(\tau-y)}\right)\,dy\,dx\\&=&\color{red}{\frac{1-e^{-2\lambda \tau}-2\lambda\tau e^{-\lambda\tau}}{\lambda^3}}.\end{eqnarray*}$$